# Grid is not getting bound properly in IE

Tags: asp.net, gridview

My grid is not binding properly in IE and I found the reason why it is not working.
one of my column value in grid is showing video and database value is

```
<object id='video' width='462' height='407' type='application/x-shockwave-flash'
  data='http://view.vzaar.com/286291.flashplayer'>
    <param name='movie' value='http://view.vzaar.com/286291.flashplayer'>
    <param name='allowScriptAccess' value='always'>
    <param name='allowFullScreen' value='true'>
    <param name='wmode' value='transparent'>
    <param name='flashvars' value='colourSet=blue&brandText=LSAT+Freedom&brandLink=lsatfreedom.com'>

    <embed src='http://view.vzaar.com/286291.flashplayer'></embed>
</object>
```

When I comment to this column while binding, my grid is working fine and showing all next records.
But I want this column.

How to bind `<object  ....>` tag to grid so that a video can be displayed.
please tell me how to bind this

Comment: Does this throw an error, or just it just not display? If not, what does the html output look like?

Answer (score 0):

What sort of grid are you using? The standard ASP.NET DataGrid, or a third-party control? Telerik's RadGrid, for example, doesn't include any sort of video capability out of the box.